# Laravel — avif file validation

Tags: laravel, image, validation, mime-types, avif

I tried to validate avif file like I validate png or jpeg, with `mimes` rule, but Laravel determines file mime type as `application/octet-stream` and rejects it.

```php
$request->validate([
    'file' => 'required|file|mimes:avif'
]);
```

How do I validate .avif image type?

Comment: is the mime type declared on your server ? https://shortpixel.com/blog/avif-mime-type-delivery-apache-nginx/

Comment: The problem lies in PHP Fileinfo extension and appears not only on server, but locally